# $GET doesn't seem to work if not in the same page

Tags: php, html

I'm currently new to php and I'm trying to understand how $GET works across pages.

So, in my page 2 I have this code in my link:

```
href="?reward1=true"
```

And in page 1 I have this:

```
if (isset($_GET['reward1'])) {
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Test");</script>';
}
```

It works if both pieces are in the same page, but not if they are in separate pages. Why?

Comment: So what goes around the `href="?reward1=true"` Thats not a complete HTML element

Comment: <a> Why would it matther if it works when beeing in the same page, maybe i should somehow pass it to that page ?

Comment: $_GET is populated based on whatever is in the URL query string.

Answer (score 1):

`$_GET` is a variable that is repopulated every time a new HTTP request is made to the server. A "request" is any HTTP interaction done with your application. If you download the html content for the page, and 3 more requests for your php app are issued in that page  (images, ajax calls, iframes, etc), that's 4 requests in your php code. If you make 2 AJAX calls to your server, that is still 2 separate requests, even if they were issued from the same loaded document on the same client.

The value of `$_GET` does not carry across requests -- it is reset each time. For instance, if you access `page2.html?foo=bar`, and then click on a link `<a href="page1.html?baz=quux">page1</a>`, the `$_GET` during the second request will match parameters from the target link, and none of the first.

If your overall goal is to carry state between the requests, you will have to either propagate the parameters from the query string (e.g. `reward1`) when you generate the link templates to the second page, or keep track of parameters on the server, e.g. inside session variables.

If the first page is *only* ever directly visited from the second, you might be able to extract the parameter from the previous page by consulting the `Referer` [sic] HTTP header, but I would recommend that only as a last resort, or as a learning exercise. Referer headers are not always reliable, especially when going from https to http, or when redirects are involved.

Comment: Thank you for explanation! I'll rather stay wih AJAX.

Comment: In your php code, `$_GET` contains parameters of a web request if it is made using the `GET` [method](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/http/http_methods.htm). You don't have to choose between ajax or not ajax, you can make `GET` requests any way you see fit. I've added a note about ajax -- from the server's perspective, it still is a different request even if you're doing ajax from the same page.