# How to call PHP function from another file using HREF

Tags: php, html

Before i start i want to let you know tham I'm using sessions, okay I have a

```
<a href="#Reward1">
```

All my server side stuff is in file named `server.php`

How can i call a function `x` from `server.php` after clicking `href` in `index.php`

Comment: Why not address the open questions on [yesterdays post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52451799/get-doesnt-seem-to-work-if-not-in-the-same-page) first? Why do you think sessions relevant? Why use an anchor now instead of GET params? This is still way too little context.

Comment: I honestly don't know if sessions mathers, I'm not a senior coder, just a starter, the thing is that server.php handles all my users and sessions, @user9741470 answer below is what i need, but how to stop it from redirecting? I may use AJAX but I dont have any example.

Comment: You should google up a few tutorials then. If you're a newcomer than AJAX isn't the first thing you should go for. Also this should have been part of your question (once you tried something, edit it in).

Answer (score 1):

Try use querysting:

```
<a href="server.php?Reward1">
```

then in your server.php file

```
    if(isset($_GET['Reward1'])){
     // call your function();
    }
```

or on the same page:

```
<?php
require_once 'server.php';

if(isset($_GET['Reward1'])){
// your function(); callback
}

?>
<a href="?Reward1">
```

Comment: It works, but the page im calling it from gets redirected to server.php.

Comment: In the first case, the redirects is normal. In the second one, you will stay on the same page, this because you've required the file on the page where the `?Reward1` querystring is located so all the code of `server.php` is loaded inside the same page.

Comment: No, it doesn't stay at the same page since I'm calling it from index.php.

Comment: Yes, you can also use ajax.