# Why AJAX is not executing function? Using HREF

Tags: php, html, ajax

index.php

```
<a href="#" onclick="doSomething();"></a>
function doSomething() {
    $.get("server.php?test");
    return false;
}
</script>
```

And this is response that server.php should give

```
if(isset($_GET['test'])){
echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("hello!");</script>';
}
```

Comment: New account, [huh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52455771/how-to-call-php-function-from-another-file-using-href?noredirect=1#comment91854236_52455771)? That's still not more attempts than before. Any URL and HTTP request debugging?

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things:

- The request parameter still required `x=y` for PHP to see it.

  ```
   #                     ↓↓
   $.get("server.php?test=1");
  ```
- For **testing**, avoid [`isset`](http://php.net/isset), but enable [`error_reporting`](http://php.net/error_reporting)

  ```
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
  #   ↓↓↓↓
  if (    $_GET['test']) {
  ```

  `isset` is meant to suppress warnings, *after* you verified everything is working as intended. Don't use it habitually.
- Use your browser dev tools <kbd>F12</kbd> / network tab to inspect what GET parameters were sent to your script.     Include that in your question.
- The echoed `<script>` will do nothing with your current use of `$.get(…);`. Instead just output a text response for testing, and:

  ```
  // alert out the response
  $.get("srv?test=1", function(data, s){
      alert(data);
  });
  ```

Comment: Thank you for your precious time spent answering this question.